# Mysql INSERT INTO and UPDATE won't work properly

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, foreach, mysqli

```
$name = array('maxgebruikers' => $_POST['maxgebruikers']);
$name1 = array('maxplaylist' => $_POST['maxplaylist']);
array_push($name,$name1);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM organisation_settings WHERE organisation_id = '{$organisatieID}'");
if(mysql_fetch_assoc($result) == 0)
{
    foreach($name as $type=>$value) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO organisation_settings (type, value, organisation_id)
    VALUES('{$type}', '{$value}' ,'{$organisatieID}')");
    print_r($name);
    }
}
else
{
    foreach($name as $type=>$value) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE organisation_settings 
    WHERE organisation_id = '{$organisatieID}'(type, value, organisation_id)
    SET VALUES('{$type}', '{$value}' ,'{$organisatieID}')");
    print_r($name);
    }
}
```

As you can see at the picture, I want where type is

[image]

like my array;

[image]

It won't insert correctly, where and what is the error in the code?

I know I should use mysqli function, but it is not the point now.

Comment: Do the values have info in them? What do the queries output when you print them? What does $result output?

Comment: as you can see my array; http://imgur.com/HttqD4A. $result gives a resource id

Comment: I meant to see the output of your $result and your mysql_query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use array_push to add $name1 to $name.
so your name array now looks like this:

```
$name = array('maxgebruikers' => $_POST['maxgebruikers'], 
               array('maxplaylist' => $_POST['maxplaylist']));
```

you have now got an array in your $name array.
but when you call it you only call the second value of this $name array.
after that you need to call the first value of the $name1 array within the $name array.

I hope you get what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use array like this,

```
$name = array('maxgebruikers' => $_POST['maxgebruikers'],
              'maxplaylist' => $_POST['maxplaylist']
);
```

now you dont have to use array_push if you need you must create new array.

in your code you are changing $name with $name1 so it doesnt work, actually works..

Answer (score 1):

This is because you put an array in an array. If you want to make it work you'll need te redifne your variables. See my PHPFiddle http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zsw-jdj